# Sidenav in dynamic tabs (Angular Material) is only working for the first tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab, angular16, mat-sidenav

For my web application I dynamically create tabs with *ngFor and each tab includes a sidenav-container with the sidenav and content. For each tab it should be possible to show and toggle the sidebar.

I have these components:

- app: includes the tabs and the sidenav container (mat-sidenav and mat-sidenav-content)
- header: includes the icon to toggle the sidenav
- sidenav: what should be shown inside the sidenav
- content: what should be shown inside the main content

I also do have a service to handle toggling the sidebar.

- sidenav.service: handles the toggling of the sidenav

app.component.html

```
<mat-tab-group class="content-container" mat-align-tabs="center"> 
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [label]="tab.name" >
     
        <mat-sidenav-container>
              <mat-sidenav #sidenav position="start" mode="side">  
                    <app-header></app-header>
                    <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
              </mat-sidenav>
              
              <mat-sidenav-content >
                    <app-content></app-content>
              </mat-sidenav-content>
        </mat-sidenav-container>
        
  </mat-tab>
```

app.component.ts

```
...
@ViewChild('sidenav', { static: false }) sidenav: MatSidenav

ngOnInit() {
    this.sidenavService.sidenavToggleSubject.subscribe(()=> {
        this.sidenav.toggle()
    })
}
...
```

header.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
   <button mat-icon-button class="toolbar-menu-icon" (click)="toggleSidenav()">
     <mat-icon class="toolbar-menu-icon">menu</mat-icon>
   </button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

header.ts

```
public toggleSidenav(){
    this.sidenav.toggle()
  }
```

sidenav.service.ts

```
...
public sidenavToggleSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null)

  public toggle() {
    return this.sidenavToggleSubject.next(null)
  }
...
```

**Problem:**
The sidebar does only exist for the FIRST tab. Having the first tab activated, toggling the sidebar just works as expected. But when I change to another tab and I toggle the sidebar, the sidebar of the first tab is toggled.

Example: When the sidebar of Tab1 is opened and I change to Tab 2 which does not show a sidebar and I click the icon to toggle the sidebar, the sidebar of Tab1 is closed, instead of opening a sidebar for Tab2.

For me it seems as there would be only one instance of the sidebar (which is ok, because I later want to dynamically set the content of the sidebar depending on the chosen tab), but why is it only shown on the first tab?

Comment: as a side note, you can make a `BehaviorSubject<void>` instead, so you can trigger it with `this.sidenavToggleSubject.next()`. It removes the unnecessary `null` in the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating your tabs via an `*ngFor`, so all your sidenav are generated. Angular material only "shows" one or the other, but they all exist. So your `@ViewChild` in your component only gets the first `#sidenav` it sees.

So what you would have to do is an `@ViewChildren` to get the list of `#sidenav`, so when you receive a toggle event, you check which tab is active, and toggle the `this.sidenav[activeTabIndex]` instead.

```
@ViewChildren('sidenav', { static: false }) sidenavs: QueryList<MatSidenav>;
activeTabIndex: number = 0;

ngOnInit() {
    this.sidenavService.sidenavToggleSubject.subscribe(()=> {
        this.sidenavs.get(activeTabIndex).toggle();
    })
}

onTabChange(newIndex: number) {
  this.activeTabIndex = newIndex;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! And is this a valid way to do it, or should only one sidenav be generated? I literally do not need five different sidenavs, those are later filled dynamically anyways. I am just not sure if it is a good way to do it the way I intended to.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what you are trying to achieve. I hardly understand how your tabs work. Most of the time, you display your header/menu, which never move, and the dynamic part is only the content of `<mat-sidenav-content>`, where you display the page title, then the tabs, and then the dynamic content of each tab.

Comment: The "problem" is that the tabs need to be created dynamically. And for each tab, a kind of static header with toggle-menu option is displayed. The main content and the content in the sidebar is then dynamic again for each tab